# reproducir un audio al dar click en un boton de .ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas a todos/as compañeros, tengo una pequeña duda. Estoy tratando de reproducir un audio al dar click en un boton de .ASP C# y con ese código funciona, el problema es que así estoy trayendo el audio desde una ruta absoluta y me gustaria que fuese relativa. Ya he buscado en la web y no encuentro lo que necesito. Es decir, pegar la direccion desde la carpeta de la aplicacion, algo asi como:" ..\Sonidos\correct.wav"

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //cero
        {

            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\correct.wav");
            player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta en un desarrollo web eso codigo que nos muestras no funciona, puede que estes escuchand el audio, pero es porque estas en un entorno de desarrollo en donde servidor y cliente estan en la misma PC, si llevas ese codigo a un hosting no vas a escuchar el audio en el cliente (browser)

Para reproducir audio debes usar javascript o html5 on el `<audio>` tag

```
<audio src="acorrect.wav" controls autoplay loop>
    <p>Tu navegador no implementa el elemento audio</p>
</audio>
```

[Usando audio y video con HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Usando_audio_y_video_con_HTML5)

Pero ese wav debs ponerlo dentro de la estructura del sitio web, no puede estar en el c:\

Tambien puedes evaluar librerias como ser

[soundjs](https://createjs.com/soundjs)

[Ion.Sound](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/en.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, a eso queria llegar, ya que si montaba la pagina a un servidor no funcionaria por lo que vos dices. Queria saber si habia una forma de llamarlo desde la carpeta que se contiene en el proyecto, pero veo que es mas conveniente con JS, lo intentaré, muchas gracias de igual modo.

Comment: si el archivo esta en una carpeta dentro de la estructura del proyecto, o sea que puedes llevarlo al IIS, entonces es directo una url.

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar lo que necesitaba, adjunto respuesta por si a alguien le interesa, saludos y mil gracias.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("../Sonidos/correct.wav");
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(pathToFiles);
            player.Play();
        }
```

Comment: Eso no funciona, sigues usando el SoundPlayer con lo cual la musica se reproduce en el servidor, no en el cliente. Tienes que usar codigo html o javascript

Comment: Hola leandro, entonces como podria quedar con Js? me gustaria saber. Voy a tratar de hacerlo, espero seguir contando con tu ayuda.

Comment: edite la respuesta, ali mencione algunas librerias que podrias usar para reproducir usando javascript

Comment: así como lo acabé de plantear tampoco funcionaria?

Answer (score 0):

Asi me funciona implementando Js, no se si sea la mejor opcion:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
       string script = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            var audio = new Audio();
                            audio.src = '../Sonidos/correct.wav';
                            audio.play();
                        </script>";
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "invocarfuncion", script, false);
  }
```

Comment: no sigas agregando respuestas, edita la pregunta. Ademas primero valida que poniendo ese script fijo en la pagina funcione, despues lo vuelves dinamico

Comment: La pregunta busca un objetivo y el objetivo se esta llevando acabo, solo que con diferente lenguaje. Ahora, si consideras pertinente cambiar la pregunta, lo hago, este codigo funciona perfectamente pero tengo algunas dudas con respecto a lo que ejecuta en un host y que no ya que nunca he desplegado una pagina con .aspx. Saluos.

Comment: Puedes hacer una prueba si lo necesitas, te creas una maquina virtual usando VirtualBox y la desplegas alli, accediendo desde el host con el browser. Por supuesto inhabilita el audio en la maquina virtual porque sino seguiras escuchando, entonces accede y valida si desde el cliente lo escuchas.